# Write/Read large JSONObject to/from file Android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to write/read a json object to/from a file. 
The json structure is complex and is dynamically generated.

For small json object I would just transform json to string then do string writing/reading. This causes out of memory issue when the json gets too large.

How do I stream the JSONObject directly to a file, and stream back the JSONObject directly from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look at the Android api, it seems that you want functionality similar to `JsonStringer` (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html) - but it doesn't seem like it is capable of streaming the results. Other than that, I think you'll be bound to either finding a suitable library (possibily https://github.com/yonik/noggit) or implementing your own json streamer (which I doubt would be that hard).

Comment: could you please show me a simple example of how to use noggit?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use GSON, Google's library to handle JSONs. I use it a lot for converting JSON web responses into classes.

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well, but you beat me to it. I'd add that gson can use streams to avoid the memory issues the OP is worried about.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to stream a json object directly to a file, instead of to a class instance. My json data has complex structure that is not known. If gson can do that, I'd like to ask for a simple sample code to demonstrate this functionality

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965764/how-to-parse-json-file-with-gson and here https://gist.github.com/madonnelly/1371597 for possible choices