# json (which contains few objects) to TreeMap on java

Tags: java, json, collections, deserialization, treemap

can somebody show code which deserialize json to TreeMap? Some simple example which includes example of json
I'll show what I've tried 
First of all I am newbie so forgive me
That's my json(probably i have mistakes even here):

```
{"Car":[{"mark":"AUDI_A3", "colour": "black"},
{"mark":"BMW_m3", "colour": "white"}]}
```

There is my code which does not work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        open();
    }
    private static void open(){
        try {
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\\t1.json"));
            String bf=null;
            String json= null;
            while((bf=buff.readLine())!=null){
                json+=bf;
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, SmallGuys>>(){}.getType();
            TreeMap<String, SmallGuys> Platoon = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            System.out.print(Platoon.keySet());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("There is a mistake");
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29965924/1754020

Comment: Have you looked at [Convert Json to Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map)?

Comment: just tried, have not helped
final Type Map = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, SmallGuys>>() {
            }.getType();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(buff);
            TreeMap<String, SmallGuys> data = gson.fromJson(reader, Map); // contains the whole reviews list
            System.out.print(data.keySet());

Comment: what about my json? maybe mistake is there&

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json to Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map)

Answer (score 1):

With Jackson, I put some methods:

```
public static Object convertJsonRequestToObject(HttpServletRequest pRequest, Class<?> pObject) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(IOUtils.toString(pRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), pObject);
}

public static Map<String,Object> parseJsonToMap(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    return   new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
}

public static Map<String,Object> parseObjectToMap(Object object){
    return  (Map<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().convertValue(object, Map.class);
}

//inverse
public static Object parseMapToObject(Map<?, ?> pMap, Class<?> pClass){
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(pMap, pClass);
}
```

Comment: {"batchSize":10,"batchIndex":1,"inventoryInformation":{"inventoryName":"Test","userName":"jason.gonzalez","beginDate":"2017-02-16","endDate":"2017-02-23","category":"2"}} and the entity for this JSON public class InventoryInput {
 
 private int batchIndex;
 private int batchSize;
 private HashMap<String, Object> inventoryInformation;
  
 public InventoryInput(){
  
 }
 
 //Set and Get

}

Comment: Also I can add object on the entity to convert, example:
 var user = {
   fullName: getCurrentSpotUser()
  }
  var location = {
   idLocation: spotInformation.locationId,
   user
  }
  var inventory = {
   idInventory: inventoryGeneralInformation.inventoryData.inventoryId
  }
  dataSend.inventoryInformation = {
   location,
   inventory
  };