# How to read json file into java with GSON library

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to read this JSON file with java using GSON library.
I am new to using gson libray. someone please correct my code
My JSON file looks like this:

```
{  
"tableRows":[  
  {  
     "id":"100",
     "mailContent":"Test mail content 123",
     "sentiment":"0"
  },
  {  
     "id":"200",
     "mailContent":"Test mail content 123",
     "sentiment":"0"
  },
  {  
     "id":"300",
     "mailContent":"Test mail content 123",
     "sentiment":"0"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the java code I wrote to read this file:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
public class Sample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
     try { 
        JsonElement jsontree = parser.parse(
            new FileReader(
                "/Users/kesavan-4688/Desktop/JSP-Eclipse/Sample/src/Demo/sample.json"
            )
        );
        JsonElement je = jsontree.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray ja = je.getAsJsonArray();
        for (Object o : ja)
        {
            JsonObject person = (JsonObject) o;

            String id = person.get("id").getAsString();
            System.out.println(id);

            String mail = person.get("mailcontent").getAsString();
            System.out.println(mail);

            String sentiment = person.get("sentiment").getAsString();
            System.out.println(sentiment);
        }   
     }  
     catch (JsonIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 }
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
at Demo.Sample.main(Sample.java:18)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965764/how-to-parse-json-file-with-gson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to convert a `JsonObject` to a `JsonArray` which cannot work, you need fist to get the root `JsonObject` then use `getAsJsonArray(String memberName)` to get the property tableRows as `JsonArray` as next:

```
...
// Get the root JsonObject
JsonObject je = jsontree.getAsJsonObject();
// Get the property tableRows as a JsonArray
JsonArray ja = je.getAsJsonArray("tableRows");
for (Object o : ja) {
    ...
    // Warning JSON is case sensitive so use mailContent instead of mailcontent
    String mail = person.get("mailContent").getAsString();
    ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
100
Test mail content 123
0
200
Test mail content 123
0
300
Test mail content 123
0
```