# Gson writes to the file, but can't deserialize

Tags: java, json, gson

SOLVED.

I have a question regarding the writing/reading list of objects with Gson. I have a Product class:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    public Product(String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
......
```

Then I have a class for ProductList:

```
public class ProductMenu {
    public List<Product> productList;
    public ProductMenu() {
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
......
```

I initialize my product list in another class:

```
public class ShoppingOperations {
    ProductUpdater import = new ProductUpdaterFromJson();
    private ProductMenu shopItems = import.importProducts();
.....
```

What I wanna do, to initialize my product list in the constructor, like this:

```
public class ProductMenu {
    public List<Product> productList;
    public ProductMenu() {
        ProductUpdater getList = new ProductUpdaterFromJson();
        productList = getList.importProducts();
    }
......
```

This is my method which writes to the .json file the list of objects:

```
public class ProductUpdaterFromJson implements ProductUpdater {
    public final static String PATH = "src\\shop\\products\\promenu.json5";
    @Override
    public void updateWarehouseData(ProductMenu shopItems) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        try {
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(PATH);
            gson.toJson(shopItems, writer);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the .json file looks like that. It's generated with Gson:

```
{
  "productList": [
    {
      "name": "Cheese",
      "price": 1.37,
      "quantity": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Milk",
      "price": 1.16,
      "quantity": 7
    },
    {
      "name": "Milka",
      "price": 0.66,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Potatoes",
      "price": 0.7,
      "quantity": 7
    },
    {
      "name": "Tea",
      "price": 2.1,
      "quantity": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting an error trying to read this file. The constructor expects List, but my file writer writes ProductMenu (it's the same list with products), but I have this error - Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
And this is the method to read from .json file:

```
public final static String PATH = "src\\shop\\products\\promenu.json5";
public List<Product> importProducts2() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type userListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(PATH, userListType);
}
```

How can I solve this problem. Writer writes , but impossible to read the file and initialize list with products.

**The solution I found with help of members:**

```
public class ProductUpdaterFromJson implements ProductUpdater {
    public final static String PATH = "src\\shop\\products\\promenu.json5";

    @Override
    public void updateWarehouseData(ProductMenu shopItems) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        try {
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(PATH);
            gson.toJson(shopItems.productList, writer);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<Product> importProducts() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Product> list = null;
        try {
            Reader reader = new FileReader(PATH);
            Type userListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
            list =  gson.fromJson(reader, userListType);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

And the constructor:

```
public class ProductMenu {

    public List<Product> productList;

    public ProductMenu() {
        ProductUpdater listFromJson = new ProductUpdaterFromJson();
        productList = listFromJson.importProducts();
    }
```

Comment: You parse the string `src\\shop\\products\\promenu.json5` not the content of the file

Comment: As @Jens already mentioned, at `gson.fromJson(PATH, userListType);` `PATH` is a string holding representing path, not content of file from that path. Please see [how to parse JSON file with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29965764)

Comment: @Jens Thank You, I changed that to:

`public List<Product> importProducts2() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Product> im = null;
        try {
            Reader reader = new FileReader(PATH);
            Type userListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
            im =  gson.fromJson(reader, userListType);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return im;
    }`

Now te problem is:

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: you write an object (ProductMenu) and want to read a list (ArrayList<Product>)

Comment: I made a change, as recommended to save as plain list of products:

`public void updateWarehouseData(ProductMenu shopItems) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        try {
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(PATH);
            gson.toJson(shopItems.productList, writer);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Comment: @andrulis i guess your path is wrong. Use <Classname>.class.getResourceAsStream(..) and remove the `src` in front of the path. Use a debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: @Jens With help I found solution. Added to the original post at the end. Now everything works fine, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try using ProductMenu as in serialization

```
public List<Product> importProducts2() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ProductMenu productMenu = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(...), ProductMenu.class);
    return productMenu.productList
}
```

Or serialize the plain list

```
gson.toJson(shopItems.productList, writer);
```

Comment: It shows:

_Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException_

Comment: I serialized the plain list like you wrote. The json file looks ok. But still error trying to read.

Comment: Yes. Null pointer. I use same path to write the .json file, and it works.

Comment: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
 at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
 at shop.products.ProductUpdaterFromJson.importProducts2(ProductUpdaterFromJson.java:42)_
I'm using your suggested code now:

_ProductMenu productMenu = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH)), ProductMenu.class);_

Comment: Try `gson.fromJson(new FileReader(PATH), ProductMenu.class);` Using getResourceAsStream needs a different path format

Comment: @MarcStröbel Thank You for help, found a final solution that works. I will edit post and add the final working version.